# Show latest dates from SQL table with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine two tables, so I have the user data and the actual data with statistics from the users. I combined both tables so I get one output.

```
SELECT users.username, data.followers, data.following, data.pins, users.url,   
users.created, data.avatar, data.bio, data.date
FROM users 
INNER JOIN data
ON data.userid=users.ID
ORDER BY data.followers  DESC
```

Within that data I want only the latest record to be shown per user, based on the latest date. Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just join to a query that has been grouped by to select max date by user.

```
SELECT users.username, data.followers, data.following, data.pins, users.url,   
users.created, data.avatar, data.bio, data.date
FROM users 
JOIN (select userid, max(date) as maxdate 
            from data 
            group by userid
     ) as md ON md.userid = users.id
JOIN data ON md.userid = data.userid and md.maxdate = data.date
ORDER BY data.followers  DESC
```

I had a few typos that I fixed... here it is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e7ad/2

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

I now have this, but that shows the first added records, not the last ones. 
`SELECT username, url, followers, following, date
FROM users 
JOIN (
    SELECT userid, followers, following, date, MAX(date) AS maxdate 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY userid
) AS data ON data.userid = users.ID
ORDER BY data.followers  DESC`

Comment: @Cupcake91 -- **Don't** change my query -- I wrote it like that because I was writing it correctly